# Perforce abort submit

Tags: perforce

I've tried to commit some files with p4 submit, and received the following error:

```
//path/somefile.c - must resolve //path/somefile.c#146
Merges still pending -- use 'resolve' to merge files.
```

Rather than `resolve`, I just want to abort the commit and go back to the state before the `submit`.  I want to edit the changelist before re-attempting the `submit`.

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to perforce, is there a command which will do what I'm attempting?

Comment: The submit command is already aborted. You are already in the state before the submit. You can simply edit the changelist. If you don't want to merge the changes, you can remove the file from your changelist, and if you want discard your unsubmitted work you can run 'p4 revert'.

Comment: @BryanPendleton, I find myself with the same question.  You are actually not in the same state as before, because the _p4 submit_ implicitly performs a _p4 sync_-like operation by automatically setting up for _p4 resolve_ with the latest revision of all files.  However, this may not be the desired revision that you are ready to resolve with.  There is something else required to get back to the state before this _p4 sync_ happened.

Answer (score 1):

Let me restate the problem as this:  After running `p4 submit` and it fails, you are actually not in the same state as before the submit, even if you delete the pending changelist, because the `p4 submit` implicitly performs a *p4 sync*-like operation by automatically setting up for `p4 resolve` with the latest revision of all files. However, this may not be the desired revision that you are ready to resolve with. There is something else required to get back to the state before this `p4 sync` happened.

In this state, trying to run `p4 sync#rev` to undo the resolve preparation doesn't do anything either.

I have found a solution that will definitely work in some cases, though it isn't a very clean approach and is very manual, so I would welcome better solutions, using built-in perforce commands if possible:

For each file that has pending resolution required, run `p4 revert -k` (reverts the file opened for edit, but keeps the file changes in the workspace), then run `p4 reconcile` on the file to open it for edit again.  At this point it will no longer be set up to resolve with the latest revision anymore.

Comment: The `revert -k` + `reconcile` approach seems like a lot more work than just doing a resolve with "accept yours".

Comment: I tried that as well. That doesn't leave you in the same state, since perforce thinks you have resolved with latest already. To be in the same state as before the submit you have to have a _have_ revision that matches what you started with. The false merge leaves you worse off than actually doing the full merge since the system erroneously thinks you have already merged in all work from latest revision.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using shelves, rather than simply opening files. Although, actually, you seem to have a really specific use case, so it's probably best if I stop guessing about it. I've never started a submit, then wanted to wholly undo it in this fashion. If you weren't intending to carry through with the submit, why did you initiate it? After all, once I start the submit I intend to complete it, so merging with the latest revision is generally what I **want** to do. But if you routinely intend to halt the submit, perhaps you should shelve your changes rather than submitting them.

Comment: @Bryan,  In general, the reason to abort the submit, is that someone may have submitted changes but only marked a subset of file revisions as stable.  There could be more unstable changes past those stable revisions.  Shelving the changes doesn't buy anything, because I am definitely going to submit my work eventually, but just need to merge in an exact stable fileset first.  The fact is that there are cases where someone might have made changes that are only detected when a submit fails, since checking+submitting is not an atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert (undo) your changes that have not been submitted. If you are on the command line you would run a command such as:

```
p4 revert //path/somefile.c
```

If you are using P4V then select the file in the pending changelist, right-click and select 'Revert'.

If changes have already been submitted you can back out a changelist or rollback a submitted integration if necessary. The references below give more details.

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Reverting-Unchanged-Files

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_revert.html

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/How-To-Rollback-An-Integration

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  There is no mention of wanting to revert changes, only to undo the submit operation.  @Stefan specifically states that he wants to keep working on the current edits and resubmit.

Answer (score -1):

In my case right click over the change list and a revert if Unchanged seem to do the job.

I saw this problem after a merge/integrate from the source branch to target branch.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem related to the question at all.